# IoT Edge Module - Remotely debugging python module issue

Tags: c#, python, azure, docker, azure-iot-edge

I have created two C# IoT edge modules one for the sender and another for the receiver using IoT module routing. It is working fine and I got the data in the receiver module. But I had to change the sender module as python instead of C#. For the Python module, I had to debug as attach remotely debugging. While debugging in remoteley it shows the error like

**Failed to attach (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678)**

My lauch.josn file like

```
      "name": "SenderPythonModule Remote Debug (Python)",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 5678,
      "host": "localhost",
      "logToFile": true,
      "redirectOutput": true,
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/SenderPythonModule",
          "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
      ],
      "windows": {
        "pathMappings": [
          {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}\\modules\\SenderPythonModule",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

My main.py file like

```
import time
import os
import sys
import asyncio
from six.moves import input
import threading
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(('0.0.0.0',  5678))

async def main():

    try: 
        if not sys.version >= "3.5.3":
            raise Exception( "The sample requires python 3.5.3+. Current version of Python: %s" % sys.version )
        print ( "IoT Hub Client for Python" )

        # The client object is used to interact with your Azure IoT hub.
        module_client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_edge_environment()       
        # connect the client.
        await module_client.connect()

        # define behavior for receiving an input message on input1
        async def input1_listener(module_client):
            ptvsd.break_into_debugger()
            while True:
                input_message = await module_client.receive_message_on_input("input1")  # blocking call
                print("the data in the message received on input1 was ")
                print(input_message.data)
                print("custom properties are")
                print(input_message.custom_properties)
                print("forwarding mesage to output1")

                await module_client.send_message_to_output(input_message, "output1")

        # define behavior for halting the application
        def stdin_listener():
            while True:
                try:
                    selection = input("Press Q to quit\n")
                    if selection == "Q" or selection == "q":
                        print("Quitting...")
                        break
                except:
                    time.sleep(10)

        # Schedule task for C2D Listener
        listeners = asyncio.gather(input1_listener(module_client))

        print ( "The sample is now waiting for messages. ")

        # Run the stdin listener in the event loop
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        user_finished = loop.run_in_executor(None, stdin_listener)

        # Wait for user to indicate they are done listening for messages
        await user_finished

        # Cancel listening
        listeners.cancel()

        # Finally, disconnect
        await module_client.disconnect()

    except Exception as e:
        print ( "Unexpected error %s " % e )
        raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

My routing like

```
"routes": {
          "SenderPythonModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/SenderPythonModule/outputs/*  INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/ReceiverCSharpModule/inputs/input1\")",
          "sensorToReceiverCSharpModule": "FROM /messages/modules/SimulatedTemperatureSensor/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/SenderPythonModule/inputs/input1\")",
          "ReceiverCSharpModuleToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/ReceiverCSharpModule/outputs/* INTO $upstream",
        },
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out? I am using windows os system.

Comment: In which platform are you running your Solution ? "windows-amd64" or Linux ? And are using Windows or Linux containers in Docker ?

Comment: Windows-amd64 and windows containers in docker

Answer (score 0):

Iot Edge doesn't support, to the writing of this, using module on windows device and windows container. Your probably gettin an error that the "windows-amd64" dockerfile of your module is not found because the VS code command will not generate this file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-python-module#solution-scope

> IoT Edge does not support Python modules for Windows devices.

If you have to work on windows, you have to enable linux containers in Docker and use amd64 as platform.